# How do I send a scheduled reminder email to members immediately?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

How do I send a scheduled reminder email to members immediately?

I've selected the membership types to email, selected the date to trigger but I cant set the time to trigger NOW (I can only base the time on criteria which isn't suitable).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use 0 minutes after since or start date.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) and [EmailApi](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) extension to send email after a membership is created.